# Identify corners in a photograph of a whiteboard using computer vision

Tags: computer-vision

So say I have a photograph of a whiteboard like this. I will be using computer vision to process the contents of the whiteboard, but first I need a way to identify the region of the whiteboard that are important. One way I was thinking of doing this is by drawing corners around the important area of the whiteboard. However, I need a way to detect these corners reliably. Normal corner detectors detect plenty of other corners as well, both inside and outside the target area of the whiteboard.

Additionally, the image of the whiteboard may not be taken head on, so the corners may not be right angles from the camera's perspective.

Anyone have any tips on how I can go about doing this? Does anyone have any jumping off points because I am not sure how to get started

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your region of interest (ROI) and background is clearly separated. So why don't you just use the "color segmentation" approach.

Something like this should work

```
1. Threshold : Otsu
2. Find the biggest rectangle which cover on the un-removed objects
3. Get the corners of that rectangle then rotate
```

Hope that help